# navbar is damaged when using bootstrap rtl

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, frontend

navbar is damaged when using bootstrap rtl
 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JvExCACAZcHNJEc7156QaHXTnQL3hQBixvj5RV5buE7vgnNEzzskDtx9NQ4p6BJe" crossorigin="anonymous" />`

```
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{route('index')}}">
                            <img src="/assets/images/logo/logo.png" alt="logo" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; margin-top: -12px;">
                        </a>
                    </div><!--/.navbar-header -->

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="overflow: visible;">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">{{__('pages.home')}}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#industries">{{__('pages.industries')}}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#services">{{__('pages.services')}}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#projects">{{__('pages.blogs')}}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about-us">{{__('pages.about-us')}}</a></li>
                            <li style="position: relative;">
                                <a href="#"  class="has-sub">@if(session()->get('locale') == 'ar') {{'Arabic'}} @else {{'English'}} @endif
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a style=" all: unset; color: black; padding: 5px 20px; cursor: pointer;"  href="/change-language" >@if(session()->get('locale') == 'ar') {{'English'}} @else {{'Arabic'}} @endif</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                        </ul><!-- / ul -->
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </nav><!--/nav -->
            </div><!--/.menubar -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
```

This is the code of the navbar.
I tried to make the website rtl when the direction is rtl (support rtl).